# Installing or downloading BioCro R package

Tags: r, package

I wonder how to install or download [Biocro](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/biocro/) package from Github.

I am on Windows 7.

Comment: Are `devtools` not working?

Comment: `devtools::install_github("biocro", "dlebauer")`

Comment: Thanks @JakeBurkhead. Would you mind to change your comment to answer!!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("biocro", "ebimodeling")
```

*note:* more recent versions of devtools require

```
install_github("ebimodeling/biocro")
```

Comment: This was the correct answer until I broke it (since I closed the repository to avoid confusion with the stable version on Rforge). See my answer below.

Comment: I put it back up on github so the answer here now works.

Answer (score 3):

Context: BioCro is an R package that simulates plant growth.

In the process of merging two forks of the BioCro project, I removed this from GitHub (an unstable, archived version is on Zenodo, but that is not intended for use).

Now, we keep the stable version of [BioCro on rForge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/biocro/) because it allows the package to be installed in this way

```
install.packages("BioCro", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Rforge makes it easier (for Windows users) because it does not require installing [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and devtools.

**update** We are in the process of making the development version available (and development process open) but need to first remove a few bits of proprietary code.

The `install_github("ebimodeling/biocro")` now gives the most recent stable version, which includes the ability to simulate the growth of Willow.